# Hibernate fetch with multiple associations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am doing this for my lazy load collections on entity objects :

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public T getWithAssociation(final long id, String association) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    final Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(genericType);
    crit.setFetchMode(association, FetchMode.JOIN);
    crit.add(Property.forName("id").eq(id));
    return (T) crit.uniqueResult();
}
```

I want to return an entity object with multiple lazy loaded collections *loaded*, can I do this (pass in a list and set more than association for a single criteria?) :

```
   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public T getWithAssociations(final long id, List<String> associations) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        final Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(genericType);
        for(String association:associations) {
            crit.setFetchMode(association, FetchMode.JOIN);
        }
        crit.add(Property.forName("id").eq(id));
        return (T) crit.uniqueResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes?

The [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-dynamicfetching) contain the following:

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Restrictions.like("name", "Fritz%") )
    .setFetchMode("mate", FetchMode.EAGER)
    .setFetchMode("kittens", FetchMode.EAGER)
    .list();
```

> This query will fetch both mate and kittens by outer join. See Section 20.1, “Fetching strategies” for more information.