# Hibernate relation loading

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, struts2

I'm developing a Struts2 + Hibernate + Spring application. I'm trying to load the user permissions into my session in order to recover them into the specific jsp.

The workflow is this one:

1. The user logs in
2. The user group is loaded Eagerly by hibernate

Here is the code from `User` class.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id_user_group", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = UserGroup.class)
public UserGroup getUserGroup() {
    return userGroup;
}
```

3. From the User group i recover another EAGER relation

Here is the code from `UserGroup` class

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_section_permission", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user_group", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "id_section_permission",
                    nullable = false, updatable = false)})
public List<SectionPermission> getSectionPermissions() {
    return sectionPermissions;
}
```

4. The user is saved into the session. When the login action redirects the user to his dashboard then a `refreshPermissions` method is called

Here is the code:

```
UserGroup userGroup = ((User) session.get("user")).getUserGroup();

    Map<String, Section> permissions = new HashMap<>();
    List<SectionPermission> sectionPermissions = userGroup.getSectionPermissions();
    for (SectionPermission sectionPermission : sectionPermissions) {
        permissions.put(sectionPermission.getCode(), sectionPermission.getSection());
    }
    session.put("permissions", permissions);
```

I think it's easy to understand that I simply create a map with the permission code and his relative section (in order to populate the menu and so on.

And now the problem... My tomcat shows the permission attribute as empty

[image: Tomcat manager image]

But magically if I add a `LOG.debug("Perm: {}", new Object[]{sectionPermission.getCode(), sectionPermission.getSection()});` inside the for loop then the permissions appear...

[image: Tomcat manager image]

What's happening? Am I doing something wrong with Hibernate or Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Lazy loading, so the permissions don't get loaded until you reference them. That is happening in the logging line.

Comment: I was editing my question writing that `getSection` has a LAZY fetch type... But I want to keep it lazy if possible... Do you know how can I initilize them when needed like in this example?

Comment: @IlGala http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359306/how-to-load-lazy-fetched-items-from-hibernate-jpa-in-my-controller