# JPA. FetchType.Lazy caused strange behaviour @ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-one, jpa-2.1

I'm trying to improve the performance of a project that uses JPA.

I'm using JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 5.0.1 implementation.

---

I changed the FetchType of a ManyToOne relation to Lazy, so the thing blows up.

When I just try to lookup all the records of the child object: the last record come with all empty fields and with a handler=JavassistLazyInitializer. And this strange behaviour impacts on the fields that use this objects (Like h:OneSelectMenu).

If I remove the FetchType.Lazy the thing back normal.

Some prints:

[Debug child list 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVDnr.png)

[FetchType.Lazy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOPL7.png)

Code of the second print (FetchType.Lazy):

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "Id_Usuario")
private Integer idUsuario;

// Fields ...

@JoinColumn(name = "Id_Tipo_Logradouro", referencedColumnName = "Id_Tipo_Logradouro", nullable = true)
@ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private TipoLogradouro tipoLogradouro;

@JoinColumn(name = "Id_Tipo_Usuario", referencedColumnName = "Id_Tipo_Usuario")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private TipoUsuario tipoUsuario;

@JoinColumn(name = "Id_Supervisor", referencedColumnName = "Id_Usuario")
@ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Usuario supervisor;

// Contructor, Getters Setters etc ...
```

}

```
public class TipoUsuario implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 1)
@Column(name = "Id_Tipo_Usuario")
private String idTipoUsuario;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)
@Column(name = "Descricao")
private String descricao;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 1)
@Column(name = "Possui_Supervisor")
private String possuiSupervisor;

@Size(max = 1)
@Column(name = "Possui_Meta")
private String possuiMeta;

@Size(max = 1)
@Column(name = "Recebe_Alerta")
private String recebeAlerta;

@Transient
private List<Usuario> usuarioList = new ArrayList<>();

//Contructor, Getters Setters etc ...
```

Comment: Hi, can you please add your stacktrace as text within the question? Images may get blocked and are cumbersome to read/copy from.

Comment: I wonder why you don't have ``org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException``  fired , Can you post the hibernate and persistence config

Comment: @Dubes, Ok! I changed, but the first print is not a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why**

With Lazy Loading, you are instructing `EntityManager` to NOT get these details unless someone asks for it. So, if in your transaction, you are not asking for that `property` to be fetched, you will only get a proxy to it. But if you ask that proxy for any thing related to that property, size for e.x., `EntityManager` will get that information for you *on-demand*.

Looks like you are using JSF for your view, now in this case, before your model is asking for these details, the entity manager *has already finished its job* and thus does not know it has to get those details from the DB for you again. Remember that proxies are serialized , thus to your view, it looks like your collection is null/empty.

**How to get around this**

Correct answer depends on your usage.

If the information you have currently lazy loaded is ALWAYS required to be shown in the front end, then you have no benefit of making it lazy loaded.

Else, if you need it to be displayed only when someone clicks on a drop down or something, then you can populate those values based on a JPA Query with `Fetch Joins`.

Else, if you have EJBs you can look at making your `EntityManager` extended.

Each of the options has lot of details, but you can take a look at this [blog post](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/lazy_loading_entities_in_views) from Adam Bien for more details on all options mentioned above and more!

**Update 1**: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15360333/1695393) to see how you can load the Lazy loaded properties on the server side.

Comment: The strange behaviour occur (as shown in print 'Debug child list 2') when I simply call "SELECT t FROM TipoUsuario t". A isolated call. :(

Comment: Assuming the property is tipoUsario in t, when you issue a simple SELECT, JPA will not fetch the LazyLoaded properties. You have to explicitly ask JPA to do that for you. Try changing the query to the following and let me know how it goes `SELECT t FROM TipoUsuario t JOIN FETCH t.tipoUsuario`

Comment: and here is the link to the official docs for join fetch in case you are interested. http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_fetch_joins

Comment: thanks for the help, but there's no complex type in TipoUsuario. I edited the post and included the type TipoUsuario.