# How to get lazy collection with Spring jpa repository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

What I want to do is "get all schools with its students" but It doesn't initialize student list. Some people says change it to FetchType.EAGER but I have no choice like updating it and also I don't think its a solution. Is there a way to initialize it?

```
@Service
public class SchoolService {
    @Autowired
    private SchoolRepository schoolRepository;

        public List<School> getAllSchools() {
            return schoolRepository.findAll();
        }
}


public class School {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "school_student", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "school_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")})
    private List<Student> students= new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:** I am using spring data jpa 1.10.1

Comment: If you change it to FetchType.EAGER, is it fetching the results ?

Comment: Are you seeing any error ? Try running it inside the transaction, user @Transactional.

Comment: which JPA version do you use ?

Comment: answers here give some options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359306/how-to-load-lazy-fetched-items-from-hibernate-jpa-in-my-controller  - either defining your own @Query method that eager loads, rather than using `findAll`.  Or messing around with the `@EntityGraph` annotation on your repository interface. Either way, I don't think you can use `findAll`: you'll have to have your own custom method

Comment: @Mr Spoon I agree with but entitygraph require jpa 2.1