# Eager Load a ManyToOne Lazy Collection in Spring JPA Transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have Lazy Loaded OneToMany, ManyToMany and ManyToOne collections in my Spring JPA entities. Whenever I want to load my OneToMany and MantToMany collections into my transaction, I use this trick

> school.getStudents().size()

In a similiar fashion, I would like to load my ManyToOne collection (say **School->City). How would I eagerly load my City data into my  transaction** in some 'simple way' similiar to the OneToMany collection show above.

My alternatives right now are

1. Change the ManyToOne to Eager loading
2. Write a JPQL query fetching the city while fetching the school data. But this is not very flexible if I have multiple ManyToOne entities and any additional fields involves changing the JPQL query.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Call a getter? I.e getToOne().getId()

Comment: yes, why not `school.getCity()` (in transaction scope) ?

Comment: @Frey school.getCity() throws an exception ! I think that is the normal behaviour since it is proxied because of Lazy Loading.

Comment: Option 2 is what I usually do ... or you can use `CriteriaBuilder` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load lazy fetched items from Hibernate/JPA in my controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359306/how-to-load-lazy-fetched-items-from-hibernate-jpa-in-my-controller)

Comment: You will have to load the relation in the same transaction. Exactly the same way as for collection size().

Comment: Yes, I get that as mentioned in my post. wondering if there is a method similiar to .size() *ToMany