# Issue using @Query to fetch lazy loaded association in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, lazy-loading

So I have an entity **Game** which contains

```
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> moves;
```

I only require this field for one specific call so the default behavior of Lazy fetching is the best choice. I don't have much experience with lazy loading so I looked around and it seems like the two preferred choices for implementing lazy loading are @EntityGraph and @Query. I looked into both and while I don't have a great understanding for the best use cases for each, I decided to use @Query.

```
public interface GameRepository extends CrudRepository<Game, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT g FROM Game g JOIN FETCH g.moves WHERE g.id = :id")
    Optional<Game> findByIdWithMoves(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

Seems simple and straight forward but this method does not find anything. The regular findById method returns the Game but my custom query does not find anything. I've looked up other examples like this one [How to fetch FetchType.LAZY associations with JPA and Hibernate in a Spring Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359306/how-to-fetch-fetchtype-lazy-associations-with-jpa-and-hibernate-in-a-spring-cont) and made minor changes like changing ***long*** to ***Long*** and tried the query without the Optional container so that it fits exactly but its still not working and I'm stuck.

Comment: Try changing `JOIN FETCH` to `LEFT JOIN FETCH` and `findByIdWithMoves` to `findById_WithMoves`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Thanks! Changing it to LEFT JOIN FETCH solved my problem. I'll accept if you want to post this as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arose from the fact that `List<String> Moves` is empty for the initial database fetch. So even though moves had been initialized, there was nothing for `Game` to join to and the standard JOIN will not return items without the specified association.

What I needed was a LEFT JOIN because they always returns all rows of the left side (`Game`) entity.

`@Query("SELECT g FROM Game g LEFT JOIN FETCH g.moves WHERE g.id = :id")`