# LazyInitializationException when I want to fetch All Companies

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

In debug mode, there is no problem fetching all these entities. I call findAll method and I get my company informations in details.

But I run **mvn install** and generate jar file. After that run this program with docker compose, I can not use this end point. It throws this exception below:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: tr.gov.cbfo.domain.entity.company.Company.addresses, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I change fetch type to eager for address list. But this time other lists(interests and licences) cause the same problem. I dont want fetch types to be EAGER.
How can I solve this problem?

I have this Company Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@Setter
public class Company extends BaseDatedEntity {

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    private boolean active;

    @OneToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH,
                    CascadeType.REMOVE
            }
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();


    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH}
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "company_interest",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "interest_id")}
    )
    private List<Interest> interests = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<CompanyLicence> companyLicences = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

**Service Method:**

```
@Override
public Page<Company> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    return companyRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

**Dto:**

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CompanyDetailDto extends BaseCompanyDto{
    private List<AddressDto> addresses;
    private List<InterestDto> interests;
    private List<CompanyLicenceDto> companyLicences;
}
```

```
@GetMapping(Apis.Company.COMPANY_DETAILED)
    public List<CompanyDetailDto> getCompaniesDetailed(@ParameterObject Pageable pageable) {
        return companyService.findAll(pageable).stream().map(companyMapper::fromCompany).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several solutions here.

1. You can either mark controller method or service method as `@Transactional`. That way the session won't be closed and hibernate will be able to get lazy collections.
2. Or you can write your own method in repository, something like this:

   ```
    public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Company c JOIN FETCH c.licenses )")
    public Company findAllAndFetchDetailsEagerly();
   ```

   }

Also see the similar response here: [How to fetch FetchType.LAZY associations with JPA and Hibernate in a Spring Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359306/how-to-fetch-fetchtype-lazy-associations-with-jpa-and-hibernate-in-a-spring-cont)

Comment: thanks, I have another question. Is it correct to use transactional annotation or entityManager in controller methods? What is the best practice?

Comment: The better approach would be to either use @Transactional on service level as it allows to decouple business logic from "api" level. But in your case it is even better from performance point of view to use 2nd variant - i.e. create your query on repo level, as in this case there will be 1 call to DB instead of 2-3 calls per each joined entity.

Comment: If my answer helped to solve the issue, could you please mark it as correct answer?