# Conditional loading @ManyToMany JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a user Entity and Article Entity. The fetch type of articles is LAZY. I dont need to load articles all the time but I have a case in which I need to load the user favorites articles. How can I do it conditionally?

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_favorite_articles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "userId", nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id", referencedColumnName = "articleId")
)
private List<Article> favoriteArticles;
```

Comment: you should create a custom query in your UserRepository with JPQL `fetch join` - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359306/how-to-fetch-fetchtype-lazy-associations-with-jpa-and-hibernate-in-a-spring-cont

Comment: The solution depends on what are you doing with the loaded user entity. Will it be serialized to JSON and sent as a HTTP response? Or will it be accessed in Java only?

Comment: @Mar-Z no it will not be sent as reponse, rather it will be use to add one more article in favorites. Inshort, I load the user with its favoriteArticles and now I add one more article in the favoriteArticles list and then save it. So in short it will be used to favorite or unfavorite an article for user.

Comment: This is not a problem at all. Let me provide some code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. EntityGraph

```
Optional<User> findById(Long id);
```

## 2. JPQL or HQL

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN FETCH u.favoriteArticles WHERE u.id = :id")
Optional<User> findUserWithFavoriteArticles(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment I understand that you want to add a favorite article for a user. This can be done in the service class:

```java
public User addFavoriteArticle(User user, Article article) {
    user.getFavoriteArticles().add(article);
    log.info("Article {} added to favorites of user: {}", article, user);
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

In the same way you can remove the article:

```java
public User removeFavoriteArticle(User user, Article article) {
    user.getFavoriteArticles().remove(article);
    log.info("Article {} removed from favorites of user: {}", article, user);
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

**How it works:** the User entity will be fetched initially without the list of favorite articles. Hibernate will place there a proxy instead. As soon as your code access the list with the getFavoriteArticles method, the list will be loaded from the database. It can be modified and persisted to the database.

**Please note:** for this code to work correctly you need to have a proper implementation of the hashCode and equals methods in your entities. Can be done with Lombok easily. And you should better define the collection as a Set instead of the List. Better performance.

Comment: Thanks Mar-Z, it was quite simple. Just wondering if the user has large number of articles as favorite (e.g. 2000 fav articles), then loading them does not seems good option. What could be better approach? Should we create a separate FavoriteArticle entity instead of favoriteArticles in User entity. Your thoughts?

Comment: An option for better performance would be to use a native SQL on the join table. For example `insert into user_favorite_articles (user_id,article_id) values (1,1)`